# a = {prop: a} vs a.prop = a: why is the first not a circular data structure?

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

What is the difference between the following? To me they look equivalent, but one results in a circular data structure and the other doesn't.

```
var a = {};
a = {prop: a};
JSON.stringify(a); // {"prop":{}}

var b = {};
b.prop = b;
JSON.stringify(b); // TypeError: Circular
```

Why does `prop: a` on line 2 not point to the object `a` and result in a circular data structure?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`{prop: a}` is evaluated before the assignment to `a`. When it's evaluated, `a` still refers to the original, empty, object. The result is a new object with a property that refers to the original.

In contrast, `b.prop = b` modifies the original `b` object with a new property referring to that object. The `b` on the right-hand side does not evaluate to simply "a plain object with no properties set"; it refers to a particular object, specifically the one you're modifying.

Comment: @Andrew You assign only once a value to `b`. `a` is assigned a value twice.

Comment: Thanks, I see it now. This means it's impossible to create a circular data structure just using `{}` notation, because you can't refer to the object before it's created, right?

Comment: @Andrew: Correct. You have to create the object and then edit it to be circular.

Answer (score 1):

`a = {prop: a};` creates another object, so in the first case, there are two objects, in the second case just one.

> Why does prop: a on line 2 not point to the object a

It does, it's just that you're changing the object that `a` refer to in that same line.

Answer (score 0):

This should answer your question:

```
var a = {prop:a};
console.log(a); //{prop:undefined}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the first example, you are resetting the variable. Therefore, `a.prop` refers to the original `a`. Just because you then reassign the identifier `a` doesn't change the object reference.

In the second, you are setting `b.prop` to `b` itself, but not overwriting `b`. Therefore, it will end up circular.